# Which for loop is more efficient in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

My friend and I at work are debating which of these three for loops are more efficient in C++ (just for example purposes they will loop 10 times):

```
//A) 
for(int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
    // Do stuff. 
}

//B) 
for(int i = 0; i< 10; ++i)
{
    // Do stuff.
}

//C) 
for(int i = 11; --i;)
{
    // Do stuff.
}

// D) 
// Anything you guys know that is better.
```

So which one is best and why?

Comment: The third one iterates differently from the first two. That said, the compiler will most probably optimize them all such that they are equivalent.

Comment: Compilers do optimize, you know.

Comment: Have you measured them? Depends a lot on what "Do stuff" is.

Comment: Test and measure. It depends on the host architecture, version, compiler, compiler version, compiler switches, ...

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2015. We understand that good compilers will most likely optimize these anyways we are just curious as to which one is best.

Comment: if you know compiler will optimize them to the same thing, what does "best" mean then?

Comment: `++i` is more efficient than `i++` in general but most of modern compilers will optimize away such differences. But when using iterators, You should prefer pre-increment operator instead of post-increment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Any decent compiler will not penalize you for which ever version you use.](https://godbolt.org/g/SxAlhD)
As you can see, all the loops boil down to the same code, with maybe one instruction reordered.

Go for the one that is most readable and clearly conveys what you want to do.

If you are interested in what happens at no optimizations, here you go:

[Example A](https://godbolt.org/g/gNtdwh)

[Example B](https://godbolt.org/g/th40Qh)

[Example C](https://godbolt.org/g/9eJaKZ)

As you can see, A and B produce exactly the same code even at no optimizations, and C has actually **more instructions** (and in my opinion, is far **less readable**)!

The code has been analyzed under G++ 5.3, the results can vary between different compilers. The main point is: it's a micro (nano?) optimization.

Comment: Actually this answer is compiler dependent. Try Clang and the result is different. IMO, you could implement C with less assembler code.
In any case, good point for the links, thanks.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Sure, each compiler can optimize (or not) the way it wants. The main point is that this is really micro-optimization at its finest.

Answer (score 2):

Usually pre-increment / pre-decrement is faster than post-increment/post-decrement, because post-<> require to save a temporal value for returning. This is maybe not the case for int, in which depending on the platform/compiler the result could be exactly the same. In any case, I do not expect pre-<> to be slower than post-<>.

Certain architecture has better performance for "==" than for greater /lesser. (Option C)

As an final answer:
Performance is probably similar or equal, the last could be faster in some specific cases. The down side is it slightly obscure code, so I would recommend the second option.

Comment: Thanks this was just what we were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How efficient those loops are will mainly depend on how efficient

```
// Do stuff.
```

is implemented. If ever there is a notable difference in efficiency in how you write the loop, it is very likely, that the whole loop has only little impact on the execution speed of the program as a whole (because this will only happen if `// Do stuff` makes only a small fraction of the total time taken for the loop).

In general you should not optimize anything unless you profiled your code and you know it is really worth doing so.